# Why does itertools.combinations add extra commas to the ouput and how to avoid it?

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I want to have all possible combinations of length up to 2 of the items in my list. I want it as a one-liner, I know how to do it in more lines. When I try this:

```
mylist=[1, 2, 3, 4]
[x for l in range(1,3) for x in itertools.combinations(mylist, l)]
```

I get this result with commas appended to the combinations of length 1.

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

I don't quite understand where they come from. Of course I could just delete them but that doesn't seem right to me, I'm sure there must be another way of producing this list without the extra commas. This is what I want:

```
[(1), (2), (3), (4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: ```(1,)``` indicate that they are a tuple

Comment: _Of course I could just delete them_ - how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want only to use `tuple`? this is because of **one element** in `tuple`, is not okay use `list`? like below:

```
mylist=[1, 2, 3, 4]
[list(x) for l in range(1,3) for x in itertools.combinations(mylist, l)]
```

output:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd actually prefer to have them as lists, now that you mention it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is because if there is no comma, single value tuples couldn't be tuples:

```
>>> (1,)
(1,)
>>> (1)
1
>>>
```

So what you want is impossible.

But you can convert single values tuples to in integers like this:

```
print([x if len(x) > 1 else x[0] for l in range(1,3) for x in itertools.combinations(mylist, l)])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
itertools.combinations
```

returns a Tuple.
Quoting from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.
> If you notice the equivalent code, you can see that

```
yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

It is yielding tuple.

And if there is a single element in the tuple, there has to be a comma to tell python that it is a tuple.
For instance:

```
>>> ('a')
'a'
>>> ('a',)
('a',)
```

You can actually convert it to a list:

```
[list(x) for l in range(1,3) for x in itertools.combinations(mylist, l)]
```